# Can Spring Boot Eureka + Zuul operate on the same service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

Can one microservice be both Eureka Server and Zuul Proxy (Gateway) ? An example of application.properties would be appreciated.

I've tried to set it up, but I can't manage to get the proxy working. This is mine application.properties files:

```
# server.port=8083
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=gateway
# Zuul
#zuul.routes.postgres.url=http://localhost:8081
zuul.routes.postgres.service-id=postgres
#zuul.routes.postgres.path=/user/**
#zuul.routes.mongo.url=http://localhost:8082
zuul.routes.mongo.service-id=mongo
#zuul.routes.mongo.path=/**
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
#Register url for client
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
#timeout
#eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=0
# Security
token.expiration.time=1800000
token.secret=
```

And postgres microservices properties:

```
# Server config
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=postgres
```